# Is there a Google service like Notion?

Tags: web-apps, google-apps, google-drive

I want to create a document that contains text, links, images, audios, and videos as same as in **Notion**.

I like to use **Google Drive**, but I think that **Google Docs** is not suitable to do that!

Does **Google** provide any service like **Notion**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it need to be from Google specifically?

Comment: @Alejandro Because I am using Google Drive in my work all time, and I am creating a folder for each project contains its files, then share it with my teammates, so I don't want to distract my teammates over several services.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't an offering in the Google space for anything like Notion.so